# .Net6 и EF: ошибки в БД

Tags: entity-framework-core

На ПК, на котором разрабатывал проект слетели миграции и я создал всё новое. Теперь при публикации проекта происходит вот такая байда:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
          Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          CREATE TABLE [Configs] (
              [Name] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
              [Value] nvarchar(max) NULL,
              CONSTRAINT [PK_Configs] PRIMARY KEY ([Name])
          );
    Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (В базе данных уже существует объект с именем "Configs".)
     ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): В базе данных уже существует объект с именем "Configs".
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
       at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
       at rnrmm.Classes.RnrmmInit.CreateDataDbAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, RnrmmdbData datacontext) in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Classes\RnrmmInit.cs:line 48
    ClientConnectionId:b850cd3f-b310-4092-a5bf-9146c7093658
    Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
```

Проблема в том, что данные из БД необходимо сохранить!

Comment: [Code First Migrations with an existing database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло